# Discord Python Rewrite - Custom Server Prefixes Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried these code

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(float)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(float)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = ','

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, float, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as float:
        json.dump(prefixes, float, indent=4)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def prefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed succesfully, now my prefix for this server is: "{prefix}"')
```

and i got these erors

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", >line 312, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 943, in on_message
> await self.process_commands(message)
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in process_commands
> ctx = await self.get_context(message)
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 853, in get_context
> prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 798, in get_prefix
> ret = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line >331, in maybe_coroutine
> value = f(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Project 01\index.py", line 20, in get_prefix
> return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
> KeyError: '744103149471662152'

Please help, it was working a few weeks ago.

Comment: Can you explain what `json.load(float)` and `json.dump(.., float,..)` do? Did you mean `f`?

Comment: I tried changing it to F to Float and it's the same error

Answer (score 0):

The server ID is not in the JSON File

Add it manually OR Kick the bot from that server and re-invite it again

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First, you are running `json.loads(float)`. Float is a function, not the file. I edited the code you posted, try using this:

```py
def get_prefix(client, message):
with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = ','

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def prefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed successfully, now my prefix for this server is: "{prefix}"')
```

(I also fixed some spelling errors in your messages)

If that still gives you the error, kick the bot and re-invite. Should work then.

Comment: sorry for the late awnser, i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('./database/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

you did right load `float` instead of writing `f`
and check if the server id in the json file
try edit it manual or kick the bot and invite it again

Answer (score 0):

Uhh your code may be right but just use `f` instead of `float`
But IG the problem is that you have not put `{}` in your JSON file so it is not taking that input.